# What is the Most Easiest way to obtain a callback Request?

Tags: php, callback, get

I'm not experienced with web servers and general handling of the requests.

What I need to is simply test out the [Twitter's OAuth2](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token) protocol. Specifically, once request is made by user (in case by me manually), I need to have a server listening for this specific URL:

> https://www.example.com?state=state&code=VGNibzFWSWREZm01bjN1N3dicWlNUG1oa2xRRVNNdmVHelJGY2hPWGxNd2dxOjE2MjIxNjA4MjU4MjU6MToxOmFjOjE

What could be the easiest way for listening for this and obtaining the code key simultaneously? From there I can go further manually again.

P.s: I can do it on Php server, Local or from VM Instance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any webserver can do this. e.g. with a PHP script you could specify `https://www.example.com/callback.php?state=state&code=VGNibzFWSWREZm01bjN1N3dicWlNUG1oa2xRRVNNdmVHelJGY2hPWGxNd2dxOjE2MjIxNjA4MjU4MjU6MToxOmFjOjE` as the URL and then a script named callback.php in the webserver would run, and could read the URL variables via $_GET. So really, it's just the same as writing code to listen for and process _any_ http request. There's nothing special about it. It's unclear how/where you're stuck, exactly.

Comment: (Obviously for Twitter to be able to access the URL, it needs to be on a registered domain and accessible over the public internet, so running this on your local machine is going to be a non-starter. You could _develop_ and _test_ it locally of course (by using something like Postman to manually make requests to it with a similar format, to ensure it reads the data as expected) and then deploy it to an internet-facing server.

Comment: @ADyson It kind of confused me about that something have to be constantly running. So, once I got the GET variable then it's easy to forward via mail. Thanks for clarity, let me try it on my web server.

Comment: Twitter doesn't need access to this URL; the user gets redirected back to this URL _in their browser._ So for testing purposes, any local address will do. (As long as Twitter lets you input it into the app settings, they might have limitations on that.)

Comment: Sorry yes CBroe is right, it's the user which needs access to it in their browser, not twitter. I beg your pardon. But either way, a regular user of your application will still presumably need access from anywhere across the internet. For testing, again, local will do, at least when _independently_ testing the URL meets the specification. As Cbroe also rightly says, it's possible Twitter won't like it if you don't specify a real domain as the URL when configuring it from their end, but you'll have to see.